# how to antd menu horizontal mode

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

```
const Navigation =()=>{
return (
    <>
        <Menu mode={"horizontal"}  style={{
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-around'}} theme={"light"}>
            <Menu.Item key={"home"} >
                홈
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key={"message"}>
                쪽지
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key={"post"}>
                게시판
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key={"homepage"}>
                홈페이지
            </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>

    </>
)}
```

I use react js and antd.
I want to give the items Menu.Item justify-content as space-around. But it doesn't work like the picture. What should I do?
Menu.Item should be spaced evenly, but it doesn't.
[image]

Comment: Can you look in your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being implemented?

Comment: i think you shouldn't do this. the antd menu has responsive behavior as adding "..." if menu gets to long, i don't know if your changes will break this behavior.

Comment: maybe just use the grid and your own buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just set the width of each `Menu.Item` to 25% and remove the styles from `Menu`.

but changing this is not a good idea i think, as it will break some menu behavior of antd. maybe leading to some unexpected behaviour.

```
const Navigation =()=>{
return (
    <>
        <Menu mode={"horizontal"} theme={"light"}>
            <Menu.Item key={"home"} style={{ width: '25%' }}>
                홈
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key={"message"} style={{ width: '25%' }}>
                쪽지
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key={"post"} style={{ width: '25%' }}>
                게시판
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key={"homepage"} style={{ width: '25%' }}>
                홈페이지
            </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
    </>
)}
```